# DC on-load switch (with overload and short circuit protection)

Tags: mosfet, switches, relay, dc, load

I have an application where I shall switch a DC load ON and OFF (with DC input), but have also to provide overload and short circuit protection. Switching voltage is 400VDC and the load is 2KW.
I need to control the switching remotely by a 24V signal.

In future, I may also need to do the same with AC input (but this is for future).

What would you recommend as a simpler solution (that would minimize circuit design and manufacturing): MOSFET, relays or even circuit breakers (CBs).

Many thanks!

Comment: K=Kelvin, k=kilo. What is used today in the industry? A motor protection CB and a contactor (big relay).

Comment: More information is needed on the load, motors are different from heaters ..etc. 24V controlled contactors have been around for a long time. Unless you are experienced in this area (I doubt it based on your question) do not build it yourself purchase commercial equipment approved for your load.  You also need to take into consideration the fault currents you will encounter in a fault condition and protect for that. You might consider getting an electrician to install it properly. If you goof it has a good chance of maiming or killing you.